# Mercadopago Checkout Javascript Mobile

Tags: php, javascript, mercadopago, mercadolibre

Tengo la implementación realizada para desktop y funciona correctamente en modo modal

```
 function openCheckout() {
            $MPC.openCheckout({
                url: "{{mp_preference.response.sandbox_init_point}}",
                mode: "modal",
                onreturn: checkoutReturn
            });
        }
```

El problema es que en mobile, si bien funciona, en vez de abrir un modal, me redirecciona al sitio de mercado pago... en desktop cerras el modal y te ejecuta: onReturn

```
function checkoutReturn(json) {
            var mp_pago_id = json.collection_id;
            if (json.collection_status == 'approved') {
                notificar('Pago acreditado');
                guardaPaymentId(mp_pago_id);
            } else if (json.collection_status == 'pending') {
                notificar('El usuario no completó el pago');
                guardaPaymentId(mp_pago_id);
            } else if (json.collection_status == 'in_process') {
                notificar('El pago está siendo revisado');
                guardaPaymentId(mp_pago_id);
            } else if (json.collection_status == 'rejected') {
                notificar('El pago fué rechazado, el usuario puede intentar nuevamente el pago');
            } else if (json.collection_status == null) {
                notificar('El usuario no completó el proceso de pago, no se ha generado ningún pago');
            }
        }
```

En mobile no ejecuta porque se va de la pantalla donde estaba, no se si es un bug o algo más tengo que agregar en mobile para que funcione.

Saludos!

Comment: como haz hecho para que reconozca el  $MPC?

Comment: ¿Podrías marcar la respuesta como aceptada por favor? Ayudarás a colaborar con la buena salud del sitio :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por defecto el checkout básico de javascript para mobile redirecciona a la página de mercadopago por una cuestión de tamaño de pantalla.
Una posible solución para esto es configurar las preferences del objeto, definiendo un backurl y que redireccione. Ejemplo de código:

```
$mp = $this->mpObject();
            $out = array();
            $url_compra = base_url("perfil-pedido/" . $compra->getId());
            foreach ($compra->getRenglones() as $cada_renglon) {
                $array_renglon["title"] = $cada_renglon->getProducto()->getNombre();
                $array_renglon["quantity"] = $cada_renglon->getCantidad();
                $array_renglon["currency_id"] = "ARS";
                $array_renglon["unit_price"] = $cada_renglon->getPrecio();
                $out["items"][] = $array_renglon;
            }
            $out["back_urls"] = array("success" => $url_compra . '?e=' . MP_ESTADO_SUCCESS, "failure" => $url_compra . '?e=' . MP_ESTADO_REJECTED, "pending" => $url_compra . '?e=' . MP_ESTADO_PENDING);
            $out["auto_return"] = "approved";
            $out["merchant_order_id"] = $compra->getId();
```

Comment: me sucese algo similar podrías mirarlo? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/318270/mercadopago-checkout-back-urls-no-funciona