# Mercadopago Checkout Back_URLS No funciona

Tags: mercadopago

Estoy implementando el siguiente código para crear un botón de pago integrando el `Checkout` de ***MercadoPago*** en mi sitio que funciona bien en *desktop* pero al hacer una prueba real en producción desde un *smartphone* no funciona, nunca redirecciona a la página `"success approved"` simplemente queda en la página de gracias de *MercadoPago*, cuando debería redireccionar a la misma luego de 4 segundos. No sólo eso, tampoco me redirecciona al sitio cuando toco el botón volver al sitio.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

```
<?php
// SDK de Mercado Pago
require __DIR__ .  '/extensiones/vendor/autoload.php';

// Agrega credenciales
MercadoPago\SDK::setClientId("escondoesto");
MercadoPago\SDK::setClientSecret("escondoesto");

// Crea un objeto de preferencia
$preference = new MercadoPago\Preference();

// Crea un ítem en la preferencia
$item = new MercadoPago\Item();
$item->title = '1 par + ENVÍO GRATIS';
$item->quantity = 1;
$item->unit_price = 1850;

$preference->items = array($item);
$preference->back_urls = array(
    "success" => "https://www.rositarococo.com/gracias-pago.html"
);
$preference->auto_return = "approved";
$preference->payment_methods = array(
  "excluded_payment_types" => array(
    array("id" => "ticket")
  )
);
$preference->save();
?>

<form  action="/procesar-pago" method="POST">
      <script
   src="https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/integrations/v1/web-payment-checkout.js"
   data-preference-id="<?php echo $preference->id; ?>">
  </script>
</form>
```

Comment: Puduste solucionarlo? Yo estoy con el mismo problema ahora...en desktop todo funciona bien pero cuando hago la prueba por web mobile no me redirecciona y ni siquiera me muestra el botón de volver al sitio

Comment: no funciona es un desastre volví a usar links de pago estáticos lo cual sigue siendo malo porque no puedo pasar parámetros a la venta para luego machear pagos ni hablar que no redirecciona forzosamente a la página de gracias luego del pago exitoso

Answer (score 2, accepted):

parece increible, tenia el mismo problema. el tema en mi caso, en modo sandbox, dependiendo si era desktop o mobile, era la url absoluta o relativa dependiendo del dispositivo.

desktop absolutas...mobile relativas...

Comment: Podés mostrar ejemplo cómo lo solucionaste?

Comment: Basicamente me fijo si es mobile o desktop

 <?php 
 
  function isMobile()
  {
     return preg_match("/(android|avantgo|blackberry|bolt|boost|cricket|docomo|fone|hiptop|mini|mobi|palm|phone|pie|tablet|up\.browser|up\.link|webos|wos)/i", $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]);
  }
 if(isMobile())
 {
   $urlmp = "/landings/preparandoPago_cursos_success_mp.php";
 }
 else 
 {
   $urlmp = "https://www.dominio.com/landings/preparandoPago_cursos_success_mp.php";
 }
 ?>

Comment: despues de esto... imprimo esa url en el boton de ir a pagar.


<form action="<?php echo $urlmp; ?>" method="POST">
 <script
src="https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/integrations/v1/web-tokenize-checkout.js"
 data-public-key=""
data-transaction-amount="<?php echo $_GET['skuProducto']; ?>"
 data-summary-product-label="<?php echo $_GET['nombreProducto']; ?>"
 data-button-label="Click para pagar con Mercado Pago" 
data-summary-product="<?php echo $_GET['skuProducto']; ?>" ></script></form>

Comment: te puse de ejemplo el form con el script de mercado pago acotado por la cantidad de caracteres de este mensaje, reemplaza con la variable la url a donde haces el post.

Comment: a todo esto, a mercado pago le mande un ticcket que nunca me respondieron, asi que analizando los por ques, tal cual ustedes, url relativa no funciona en desktop y url absoluta no funciona en mobile en que se me ocurrio plasmarlo asi. En teoria esto arreglaria otros problemas mobile.