Problema con redirección al pagar con app de Mercado Pago
Estoy desarrollando un sistema con laravel. El problema es que al pagar desde el celu no redirecciona a las back_urls pero si en la versión de escritorio. Me cansé de buscar y no puedo dar con la solución. Alguien que me ilumine? Dejo el código del controlador y el código de la vista.
Muchas gracias a todos por la ayuda!
Vista
<script src="https://sdk.mercadopago.com/js/v2"></script>
    <script>
        const mp = new MercadoPago('{{ $public_key }}', {
            locale: 'es-AR'
        });
        mp.bricks().create("wallet", "wallet_container", {
            customization: {
                visual: {
                    buttonBackground: 'white',
                    valuePropColor: 'white',
                },
            },
            initialization: {
                preferenceId: '{{ $preference->id }}',
            },
        });
    </script>

Controlador
$preference = new MercadoPago\Preference();
        $item = new MercadoPago\Item();
        $item->id = $reserva->uuid;
        $item->title = 'Reserva de Cabañas Viñedos de la Luna';
        $item->description = 'Reserva de Cabañas Viñedos de la Luna';
        $item->picture_url = asset('assets/pagina/img/logo.png');
        $item->quantity = 1;
        $item->unit_price = 100;

        $preference->items = array($item);

        $preference->back_urls = array(
            "success" => route('pagina.resultadopago').'?resultado=exito',
            "failure" => route('pagina.resultadopago').'?resultado=fallo',
            "pending" => route('pagina.resultadopago').'?resultado=pendiente'
        );

        $preference->external_reference = $reserva->uuid;

        $preference->expires = true;
        $preference->expiration_date_from = Carbon::now()->toISOString();
        $preference->expiration_date_to = Carbon::now()->addDays(30)->toISOString();

        $metodospagosexcluidos = [['id' => 'pticket']];
        $preference->payment_methods = ["excluded_payment_methods" => $metodospagosexcluidos, "installments" => 12];

        $preference->notification_url = 'https://vinedosdelaluna.com.ar/verificar';

        $preference->statement_descriptor = 'Viñedos de la Luna';

        $preference->auto_return = "approved";
    
        $preference->save();


Mira esta pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/318270/mercadopago-checkout-back-urls-no-funciona. Parece ser el mismo problema
